# Picking up a Lync installation where someone else left off

Tags: installation, lync, ms-office-communicator

I'm about ready to pick up a Microsoft Lync Server 2010 installation from someone else and I am not exactly sure where he left off.  I'm not sure if I'm going to get any notes on his progress either.

I remember doing our OCS 2007 installation about three years ago and it was a massively complex setup process that had to be followed step by step.  Has the Lync 2010 setup improved any?  Is anybody familiar with the setup utility, and does it pick up where it left off gracefully?

Also, any gotchas or lessons learned you could share would also be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lync is a lot better than OCS 2007, this is due to the topology builder among other things.

Not to mention that there is no mmc anymore, but you do get a pretty good silverlight web app and a great powershell filled with goodies. See the lync technet docs, as they are very well done and constantly being updated.

See:
Jeff Schertz's blog for a good step by step intro:
http://blog.schertz.name/2010/09/lync2010rc-deployment-part1/

Also there is a good book out by Alex Lewis and Crew: [http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Lync-Server-2010-Unleashed/dp/0672330342/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1304263752&sr=8-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672330342)

Comment: I ended up gutting everything he had done before and starting over.  I got the server pool up and running on Friday and transitioned two user's over for testing.  So far so good.  Believe it or not I started reading your book reference on Thursday.